# Angular ivh-treeview all nodes expand by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, treeview, frontend

Working on AngularJS ivh-treeview.

I want to see all child nodes expanded by default.

Currently this is my tree structure:

```
 $rootScope.nodes= [{
        label: 'node1',
        value: 'node1',
        enable:true,
        children: [{
            label: 'child1',
            value: 'child1',
            enable:true,
            children: [{
                label: 'child2',
                value: 'child2',
                enable:true,
            }]
        },{
            label: 'node2',
            value: 'node2',
            enable:true,
        }]
    }];
```

Currently there is a **+** sign on left side of **child1** label.
It also has a sub child which is **child2** but i have to click on 
the **+** sign to view it.

Also when i drag a node in **child1** i am not able to see it 
and i have to click on the **+** sign to view it.

I want to view all the child nodes by default. I mean there should be no
need to click on the **+** sign when i drag a new node.

I had found a solution for this which is :

**ivh-treeview-expand-to-depth="2"**

but in this we have to specify a value...like above...i want
to pass something in this like

**ivh-treeview-expand-to-depth="*"** OR **ivh-treeview-expand-to-depth="infinite"**

So that i can view all the child nodes by default or when ever i drag a new node it should be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ivh-treeview-expand-to-depth="-1"` to expand all nodes by default. See the *Expand by Default* section of the project's README: https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview#expanded-by-default. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @jtrussell....for some reason -1 is not working...it works only on positive integers....:-/

Comment: @Simon seems to be working in the demo: http://jsbin.com/ruxedo/edit?html,js,output - can you provide an example of it non working?